# res.render sweetalert on ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, sweetalert

How to show alert in .ejs file from app.js code

I am using sweetalert npm

```js
  //if success redirect another page 
  
  if(data.type == 'success')res.render('user.ejs',{user:user});
  
  // if error show alert on page login.ejs
  
  if(data.type == 'error')swal("Oops!", "Something went wrong!", "success")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the app.js:

```
if(data.type == 'error')
  {
    res.render('login', {alert: true, alertTitle: "Oops!", alertMessage: "Something went wrong!"})
  }
```

in the login.ejs

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  if (alert === true) {
    var alert = <%= alert %>
    var alertTitle = <%= alertTitle %>
    var alertMessage = <%= alertMessage %>
    swal(alertTitle, alertMessage, "success");
  }

})

</script>
```